# how to see a full image of deep neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, graphics, keras, deep-learning

How it is possible to see in Keras or Tensorflow the graphical structure of deep neural network? I made its model and see output of "plot_model" but I want to see the graphical similar to this image.

[image: click to see the image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a common problem within the community.  There are many 'visualization' APIs and libraries out there for NNs and CNNs, but many of them are flat and not what you're looking for.  A couple of months ago, **I bookmarked this Github project: https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet** .  It looks like exactly what you want, or at least very close.  I've never personally used it, but I plan to at some point.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For Tensorflow at least, you can use Tensorboard
[Tutorial and Explanation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)

It also features [Graph visualization](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz), which is what you are looking for.
Still, not equal to your sample picture, but good ennough I think.

Comment: Thanks but what I know about tensorboard is that it is show the details of layer such as activation function,... but what I want is that very few details of network!